# Saving User RAM/Memory: Saving the video source before opening and playing, and removing it after closing and pausing

Tags: javascript, memory, html5-video, webflow

**Currently**
I have a [website](https://ergotherapie-brackwede.webflow.io/#startseite-section-unternehmen) where if you click on a profile, a video popup shows up and plays automatically. When the user clicks on the "X"/Close Button the video pauses automatically.

**My Intention & Problem**
Im trying to save RAM / memory on devices that do not got much, because if open up many videos after one and another.. it starts lagging and on safari the website reloads, which needs prevention.

**The Solution**
So i saw the solution to remove the "src" value after pressing on "X"/Close and the video pauses & adding the source again when the user clicks on the profile and so the video is able to autoplay without saving the file in the memory.

**My Code**

'

```
function memberVideo(click, popup, video) {

  $(click).on('click', function(event) {
    console.clear();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(popup)[0].style.display = "flex";
    $(video)[0].play();
    
    $(".image-popup-close").on('click', function() {
        $(video)[0].pause();
    });
  });
};

memberVideo("#jana-hilmert-thomas", "#jana-hilmert-thomas-popup", "#jana-hilmert-thomas-video");'
```

[Watch on Webflow](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/ergotherapie-brackwede?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=ergotherapie-brackwede&preview=1e979a222f0ed8c54e06449599c17bc4&workflow=preview)

I tried saving the source before the click funtion via: `const source = $(video)[0].src;` 
But when i do that, the popup and everything after doesnt even show up / work and i dont understand why.

To delete the source for memory savings i included the code: `$(video)[0].src = "";` below the pause(); function, Which works. It removes the source, but i can't regain the source when i close the popup and open it again?

I tried and researched for a whole day now.. but seem to not get any real progess.. help please?

Answer (score 0):

**Code Solution**

```
function memberVideo(click, popup, video, src) {
    $(click).on('click', function(event) {
        console.clear();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        $(video)[0].setAttribute('src', src);
        console.log($(video)[0].src);

        $(popup)[0].style.display = "flex";
        $(video)[0].play();

        $(".image-popup-close").on('click', function() {
            $(video)[0].pause();
            $(video)[0].setAttribute("src", "");
            console.log($(video)[0].src);
            $(popup)[0].style.display = "none";
        });
    });
};
  
memberVideo("#jana-hilmert-thomas", "#jana-hilmert-thomas-popup", "#jana-hilmert-thomas-video", "https://assets.agentur-kaufmann.de/ergotherapie-brackwede/interview-jana-hilmert-thomas.mp4");
```